# Count occurrences of certain values in dask.dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df.head()
   day      time  resource_record  
0   27  00:00:00             AAAA  
1   27  00:00:00                A  
2   27  00:00:00             AAAA  
3   27  00:00:01                A  
4   27  00:00:02                A
```

and want to find out how many occurrences of certain `resource_records` exist.

My first try was using the Series returned by `value_counts()`, which seems great, but does not allow me to exclude some labels afterwards, because there is no `drop()` implemented in `dask.Series`.

So I tried just to not print the undesired labels:

```
for row in df.resource_record.value_counts().iteritems():
    if row[0] in ['AAAA']:
        continue
    print('\t{0}\t{1}'.format(row[1], row[0]))
```

Which works fine, but what if I ever want to further work on this data and really want it 'cleaned'. So I searched the docs a bit more and found `mask()`, but this feels a bit clumsy as well:

```
records = df.resource_record.mask(df.resource_record.map(lambda x: x in ['AAAA'])).value_counts()
```

I looked for a method which would allow me to just count individual values, but `count()` does count all values that are not NaN.

Then I found `str.contains()`, but I don't know how to handle the undocumented Scalar type I get returned with this code:

```
print(df.resource_record.str.contains('A').sum())
```

Output:

```
dd.Scalar<series-..., dtype=int64>
```

But even after looking at Scalar's code in `dask/dataframe/core.py` I didn't find a way of getting its value.

How would you efficiently count the occurrences of a certain set of values in your dataframe?

Comment: While figuring this out I realized that `dask.dataframe.drop` does only support `axis=1`. Dropping on the dataframe could have been a solution.

Comment: To get the value of the Scalar (or any other dasky collection), you need the method `.compute()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I came across `.compute()` before, but didn't gather from the documentation that it would help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases pandas syntax will work as well with dask, with the necessary addition of `.compute()` (or `dask.compute`) to actually perform the action. Until the compute, you are merely constructing the graph which defined the action.

I believe the simplest solution to your question is this:

```
df[df.resource_record!='AAAA'].resource_record.value_counts().compute()
```

Where the expression in the selector square brackets could be some mapping or function.

Comment: Little typo with the ')' within the '[]'.

Comment: This works nicely. I guess I'm just not very experienced with how to do things with pandas/dask, yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One quite nice method I found is this:

```
counts = df.resource_record.mask(df.resource_record.isin(['AAAA'])).dropna().value_counts()
```

First we mask all entries we'd like to get removed, which replaces the value with NaN. Then we drop all rows with NaN and last count the occurrences of unique values.

This requires `df` to have no NaN values, which otherwise leads to the row containing NaN being removed as well.

I expect something like

```
df.resource_record.drop(df.resource_record.isin(['AAAA']))
```

would be faster, because I believe drop would run through the dataset once, while mask + dropna runs through the dataset twice. But drop is only implemented for axis=1, and here we need axis=0.